# Require a single function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am trying to export a file that has some configuration of my jwt, so i need to get those in my router

my exported function:

```
module.exports = {
    'secret': 'sdasda',
    'expirationTime': 60*60*24*4 
};
```

**requiring the function**

```
var jwtConfig = require('../config/jwt');
```

and i get this error: **Cannot find module './config/jwt'**

the config folder is 1 path above, and the jwt file is inside :S

Any tip?

Comment: Your error says `./config/jwt`, not `..` (double dot). Perhaps the error is happening in another file, it doesn't match the code you posted

Comment: `jwtConfig` is not a function but a normal object